# Independently toggle visibility of two inline items with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Given the following layout, where `flexible box` is, well, flexible width, and the buttons are fixed width:

`|-[______flexible_box_______]-[button1]-[button2]-|`

how do I make `button1` and `button2` both independently "hideable", with a single change of a constraint priority for each?

To illustrate, the layout needs to support each of the below states:

```
|-[______flexible_box_______]-[button1]-[button2]-|
|-[___________flexible_box____________]-[button1]-|
|-[___________flexible_box____________]-[button2]-|
|-[________________flexible_box_________________]-|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iOS 9.0+, [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) takes care of this for you. Hide one of the arranges subviews and the layout ignores it. Show it again and it returns to the layout.

Before that you can do something like this set of constraints:

1. `|-[box]-(>=standard)-[button1]`
2. `|-[box]-(>=standard)-[button2]`
3. `|-[box]-(>=standard)-|`
4. `[button1]-(>=standard)-[button2]`
5. `[button1]-(>=standard)-|`
6. `[button2]-(>=standard)-|`
7. `|-[box]-(standard@700)-|`

(If you're setting this up in IB, you can pick the standard value when you edit the constraints. Otherwise, you'll need to replace "standard" with the actual value.)

Constraints 1-6 make sure the items stay in order without overlapping. Number 7 makes the box try to fill the whole space, but at a reduce priority. It will take up slack if that's available.

If you hide button1, add some huge value to the constant of constraints 4 and 5. (Actually, you may need to subtract the value. The visual format language I've used here is ambiguous about which is the first item and which is the second.) This relaxes the obstacle which was preventing the box from pushing the button off to the right, and the box takes up the slack. When you reshow it, reverse the arithmetic.

[**Update:** Actually, it's probably better to just deactivate the constraints, rather than mucking with their constants. (Set the `active` property to false.) You'll need to keep a strong reference to the constraints because they'll be removed from the view that would otherwise keep them.]

Likewise, if you hide button2, you adjust constraint 6.

It's not quite one constraint per button, but I think it's about as close as you can get.